# Burn In component testing

Tags: electrical, testing

For pre and post electrical testing of burn in components under test: what is the best way to measure current and voltage through said burn in components before and after burn in to verify if the components are still in range of its parameters on its data sheet. Basically making sure the component is still in operational condition. I need some type of a circuit to test current and voltage on these components. These components are SMC and D^2 Diodes that are placed into a socket during the burn in process. These components will be on a PCB and put into an oven. Thanks

Comment: If you need some type of date sheet correlated to the parts let me know. Also, I just need some type of circuit that can do the task listed in the main post. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'burn'? You mean you're going to fry them until they burn up? Or shove loads of current through till they burn then test them again? Or what?

Answer (score 2):

The manufacturer should provide a schematic of the circuit(s) used to measure the datasheet parameters, along with any necessary footnotes. If you want to compare your measurements to the datasheet you will need to use the same test configuration.

Comment: The data sheet it does not specify a schematic for stress testing components before and after burn in. It only states the values the component should be at for pre and post electrical testing.

Comment: Your question asks about testing "before and after burn in" and asks nothing about a schematic to be used **stress** testing. The schematics you need are for characterization testing, to measure the voltages and currents. If the datasheet doesn't have them then you need to ask the manufacturer.